# Why does my Docker cache get invalidated by this COPY command?

Tags: docker

My docker builders in CI system get destroyed after inactivity, thus losing the local cache. I am using `--cache-from` by first pulling the most recent image from quay.io repo and then using that as a `--cache-from` in the next build. 
I am running docker version `17.12.0-ce`.
Dockerfile (for the pertinent part) looks like:

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
ant \
build-essential \
software-properties-common \
libncurses5-dev \
libncursesw5-dev \
libcurl4-openssl-dev \
libboost-dev \
libfreetype6-dev \
zlib1g-dev \
r-base \
default-jdk \
python-dev \
python-setuptools \
python-pip \
python3-dev \
python3-setuptools \
python3-pip \
git \
wget \
unzip \
ghostscript \
pkg-config


RUN mkdir /software
WORKDIR /software
ENV PATH="/software:${PATH}"

RUN git clone --branch v0.2.19 --single-branch 
https://github.com/xianyi/OpenBLAS
RUN cd OpenBLAS && make FC=gfortran TARGET=NEHALEM USE_THREAD=0 && make 
PREFIX=/opt/openblas install
ENV LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/opt/openblas/lib:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}"

# Install samtools dependencies
RUN wget http://zlib.net/zlib-1.2.11.tar.gz && tar -xvf zlib-1.2.11.tar.gz
RUN cd zlib-1.2.11 && ./configure && make && make install
RUN wget http://bzip.org/1.0.6/bzip2-1.0.6.tar.gz && tar -xvf bzip2-
1.0.6.tar.gz
RUN cd bzip2-1.0.6 && make && make install
RUN wget https://tukaani.org/xz/xz-5.2.3.tar.gz && tar -xvf xz-5.2.3.tar.gz
RUN cd xz-5.2.3 && ./configure && make && make install

RUN pip install common python-dateutil cython

RUN pip3 install common python-dateutil cython

# Install numpy 1.11.3 (python2/3)
RUN git clone --branch v1.11.3 --single-branch https://github.com/numpy/numpy
COPY /docker_image/site.cfg numpy/
RUN cd numpy && python setup.py install
RUN cd numpy && python3 setup.py install
```

When I run my build with (clean machine, with nothing in cache):

```
docker pull quay.io/myorganization/myimage:tag
```

and then run the build with

```
docker build --cache-from=quay.io/myorganization/myimage:tag -f docker_image/Dockerfile -t quay.io/myorganization/myimage:newtag .
```

the build uses cache until `COPY /docker_image/site.cfg numpy/` invalidates the cache. My .dockerignore looks like:

```
.git*
```

so things changing there should not be the problem. If I accidentally omitted some important information needed, please ask and I will promptly provide that. Any ideas on what could cause the cache invalidation on this particular spot would be highly appreciated.

edit: This cache invalidation happens even if I don't change anything in the repo between builds, by doing the following: Build image using tag1, Push image
to quay.io, then on a clean machine Clone git repo, Pull image (tag1), Build image with tag2. Could it be something that changes in the numpy repo metadata? (Note: --single-branch should not, to my understanding, pull any info about other branches in that repo).

Comment: Did you ever find the cause of this? I'm having the exact same issue and the only answer on this question doesn't seem to apply since it's a single file COPY and the file does not change.

Comment: Re edit: could it be that pulling “the same” files from remote repository makes the files “different” because of creation date/modification date/owner or some other metadata generated when the pull is executed?

Comment: @DanStewart, did you solve your issue? My "COPY file1.txt /foo/file1_bar.txt" is invalidating the cache too if the build is done from different machines but "shasum1 file1.txt" gives the same hash on both machines and in the docker container.

Answer (score 40):

The docker cache for a `COPY` or `ADD` command uses a hash of the files and directories. Included in that hash are the contents of every file, and even the permissions on the files. So if any of these changed by a single byte, the hash will be different and docker will have a cache miss, forcing the line to be rerun.

From the point of the first cache miss, all remaining lines will need to be rebuilt since the preceding layer is now new and has not be used to run any of the following steps.

Comment: Are files and directories in the `.dockerignore` also considered in the hash or are they ignored?

Comment: @n00b they are ignored. Never sent to the server to be hashed.

Comment: I have the same problem. I don't know what changes, I push new commit to CI and it runs docker build. I have `COPY . .` in Dockerfile. Only `.dockerignore`'d files change, but build doesn't use cache starting from `COPY . .` line (before that cache is used).

Comment: @EugZol do you have a public example? You should consider posting a new question with a [mcve].

Comment: Turns out I forgot to add `.git` to `.dockerignore`. Oops :)

Comment: Any way to view the hash or the full contents being hashed? I have a copy of just one file that seems to get cache busted when the file does not change.

Comment: @nroose have you tried comparing a simple sha256sum on the file in different builds? As mentioned on another of your comments (on a diff question) I recently added `regctl blob diff-layer` that may help you: github.com/regclient/regclient/pull/269

Comment: @BMitch Trying to look at that. The situation is an automated build in a cloud environment, and sometimes the cache is there, and I am trying to pull the previous image to avoid building the new one, and sometimes it works and sometimes not. Just have no idea what is happening that is inconsistent.

Comment: In my case, it was my IDE files, `idea`. I already knew this, but didn't see `idea`: `.dockerignore` doesn't care about `.gitignore`

Comment: Takeaway from this answer - avoid `COPY Dockerfile somewhere/`, because when while debugging your environment and tweaking the Dockerfile, you'll invalidate the cache