# Dockerfile use npm cache

Tags: docker, npm, continuous-integration, docker-build

I have a Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:13.7
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
RUN env

# Layer for npm
COPY package.json package-lock.json ./
RUN npm ci
# Bundle app source
COPY . .
RUN git config http.sslVerify false
RUN npm run lib

RUN npm run docker-build

RUN rm -f .env
RUN ["chmod", "+x", "/usr/src/app/docker-entrypoint.sh"]
RUN ["chmod", "+x", "/usr/src/app/wait-for-it.sh"]
CMD ./docker-entrypoint.sh
```

I'm already only doing the `npm ci` if the package.json or package-lock.json hasn't changed. But I also want to avoid all the unchanged npm packages to being redownloaded. How can I make docker use the npm cache to store and reuse already downloaded packages?

Comment: Your question contains incorrect statement about `npm ci` being run only when package*.json files *have not* changed. The actual behavior of your Dockerfile is that it runs `npm ci` only when those files *have* changed.

Answer (score 0):

I think your docker cache become invalidated on command `COPY . .`.
You can check it in build logs and see lines `Using cache` and on copy command it's absent, maybe)
Check that answer
[Why does my Docker cache get invalidated by this COPY command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48551953/why-does-my-docker-cache-get-invalidated-by-this-copy-command)

Guys said that `.dockerignore` is creating to avoid coping unnecessary files and helps us ignore cache of unnecessary files.

So, it's only advice to give any thoughts.

And.. `RUN npm run docker-build` looks some strange because `Dockerfile` is creating to build image..

And you can before run `docker build .` download all sources to avoid cloning it from Dockerfile from git. (`RUN npm run lib` but I don't know what does it line)

And you can use multistage builds https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/
it is very useful when you build binary or create js bundle in first stage and copy it to second fresh system to decrease image size as much possible.

I can more describe any of these points or.. Please, could you give more information of your situation?

what does lines ?

```
RUN npm run lib
RUN npm run docker-build
```

you can set `+x` flag on host before `docker build .`

```
RUN ["chmod", "+x", "/usr/src/app/docker-entrypoint.sh"]
RUN ["chmod", "+x", "/usr/src/app/wait-for-it.sh"
```

why do you do it in `Dockerfile` ?

Comment: COPY package.json package-lock.json ./ is working, it only is executing RUN npm ci when one of the jsons changes. But I want to use npm cache even in this case because it takes forever. RUN npm run lib dowloads a lib from another git and npm run docker-build compiles the JS code for the web. But your link to multi stage builds maybe will help me.

Comment: you can try read about ADD command. and I could suggest pack your local node_modules to tar archive and unpack it inside dockerfile by command ADD https://www.educative.io/edpresso/what-is-the-docker-add-command . so your "cached" packages always be used. I never did it and maybe it is Not best solution